# Linux shell use disown on serial calculations

Tags: linux, sh

I have two scripts: `script1.sh` and `script2.sh` and I want to `disown` each of them (for external reasons I cannot use `nohup` here). How can I run one after the other?

I tried:

```
script1.sh & disown ; script2.sh & disown
```

but then both scripts are executed when I press Enter... Adding brackets does not solve the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with `disown`? (i.e., why not just `script1.sh; script2.sh`?)

Comment: @JosephSible In the script1.sh there are long term calculations launched to another server, so I need to be sure that even if my computer is shut down or is there is a connection break the calculations will continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a "shell escape":

```
( { script1.sh; script2.sh; } </dev/null &>/dev/null &)
```

Now your scripts are disconnected from the controlling terminal and owned by `init`.

In plain `sh` you may need to replace `&>/dev/null` with `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Hi @Maxim, thank you for your answer. Seems to be working, though I no longer have any terminal output... My `.sh` runs a python script which returns some information such as the progress of the calculation. These were printed with disown, but not with your solution. Any hint in that?

Comment: Also could you please explain what does "Now your scripts are owned by init" mean?

Comment: If you'd like to see the output remove the output redirection `&>/dev/null`. However, that makes the script keep the controlling terminal open, so it will receive `SIGHUP` on disconnect. You may like to redirect the output into a file instead.

Comment: Owned by `init` means the process parent pid becomes `1` (pid of `init`). In other words, the command stops being a child of your current shell, hence the escape from the shell.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanations! I accepted your answer as it answers the main question here. However, I tried to redirect output to a file and to read it in real time, but then both script are executed simultaneously again... Could you give me your opinion here? I tried this command: `(script1.sh </dev/null &>test1.out & tail -f test1.out &); (script2.sh </dev/null &>test2.out & tail -f test2.out &)`

Comment: @jeannej You probably want to run `tail` in your current shell, so that it terminates when you disconnect. So, in the next line `tail -f test1.out test2.out`. Script output becomes block-buffered (chunky `tail` output) when redirected into a file, you can make scripts line-buffered with `stdbuf -oL <cmd-line>`.

Comment: so I did `(script1.sh </dev/null &>test1.out &); (script2.sh </dev/null &>test2.out & tail -f test2.out &); tail -f test1.out test2.out` but then all the scripts were launched at the same time... Did I misunderstood what you said? As for now I decided to remove the `&` after `test.out` and couple it with a `tail -f test.out` on another terminal. Thanks again for your great help!

Comment: @jeannej Updated the answer for the scripts to run one after another for you.

Comment: perfect, this works as well if I write it into a file! Thanks a lot again, too bad I cannot vote up for answers twice ;)

Comment: You are too kind, I missed the sequential requirement yesterday.